# How to use custom pins for SPI on ESP32 (pico-v3-02)

Tags: arduino, esp32

I trying to use custom pins for SPI on the pico-mini-02 board. The board has esp32 (pico-v3-02). I'm using Arduino IDE (with arduino-esp32) and windows 10.

When I try to use the SPI example (multiple buses example), I'm getting `Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.` error. I have decoded the exception backtrace

```
0x40080f31: __pinMode at C:\Users\newto\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.5\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-gpio.c line 115
0x400d0f3a: spiAttachSCK at C:\Users\newto\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.5\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-spi.c line 87
0x400d0db2: SPIClass::begin(signed char, signed char, signed char, signed char) at C:\Users\newto\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.5\libraries\SPI\src\SPI.cpp line 57
0x400d0c2b: setup() at C:\Users\newto\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.5\libraries\SPI\examples\SPI_Multiple_Buses/SPI_Multiple_Buses.ino line 67
0x400d190a: loopTask(void*) at C:\Users\newto\OneDrive\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.5\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 32
0x40085fa5: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c line 143
```

The full error message:

```
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 271414342, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5856
entry 0x400806a8
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40080f31  PS      : 0x00060730  A0      : 0x800d0f3d  A1      : 0x3ffb1f30
A2      : 0x0000000e  A3      : 0x00000002  A4      : 0x3ffb8364  A5      : 0x00000001
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000004  A8      : 0x3f400674  A9      : 0xaaaaaaaa
A10     : 0xaaaaaaaa  A11     : 0x00000030  A12     : 0x3ffb82cc  A13     : 0x00000000
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000009  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0xaaaaaaaa  LBEG    : 0x400d1258  LEND    : 0x400d1265  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40080f31:0x3ffb1f30 0x400d0f3a:0x3ffb1f50 0x400d0db2:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d0c2b:0x3ffb1f90 0x400d190a:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40085fa5:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

The sketch:

```cpp
/* The ESP32 has four SPi buses, however as of right now only two of
 * them are available to use, HSPI and VSPI. Simply using the SPI API 
 * as illustrated in Arduino examples will use VSPI, leaving HSPI unused.
 * 
 * However if we simply intialise two instance of the SPI class for both
 * of these buses both can be used. However when just using these the Arduino
 * way only will actually be outputting at a time.
 * 
 * Logic analyser capture is in the same folder as this example as
 * "multiple_bus_output.png"
 * 
 * created 30/04/2018 by Alistair Symonds
 */
#include <SPI.h>

// Define ALTERNATE_PINS to use non-standard GPIO pins for SPI bus

#ifdef ALTERNATE_PINS
  #define VSPI_MISO   2
  #define VSPI_MOSI   4
  #define VSPI_SCLK   0
  #define VSPI_SS     33

  #define HSPI_MISO   26
  #define HSPI_MOSI   27
  #define HSPI_SCLK   25
  #define HSPI_SS     32
#else
  #define VSPI_MISO   MISO
  #define VSPI_MOSI   MOSI
  #define VSPI_SCLK   SCK
  #define VSPI_SS     SS

  #define HSPI_MISO   12
  #define HSPI_MOSI   13
  #define HSPI_SCLK   14
  #define HSPI_SS     15
#endif

static const int spiClk = 1000000; // 1 MHz

//uninitalised pointers to SPI objects
SPIClass * vspi = NULL;
SPIClass * hspi = NULL;

void setup() {
  //initialise two instances of the SPIClass attached to VSPI and HSPI respectively
  vspi = new SPIClass(VSPI);
  hspi = new SPIClass(HSPI);
  
  //clock miso mosi ss

#ifndef ALTERNATE_PINS
  //initialise vspi with default pins
  //SCLK = 18, MISO = 19, MOSI = 23, SS = 5
  vspi->begin();
#else
  //alternatively route through GPIO pins of your choice
  vspi->begin(VSPI_SCLK, VSPI_MISO, VSPI_MOSI, VSPI_SS); //SCLK, MISO, MOSI, SS
#endif

#ifndef ALTERNATE_PINS
  //initialise hspi with default pins
  //SCLK = 14, MISO = 12, MOSI = 13, SS = 15
  hspi->begin();
#else
  //alternatively route through GPIO pins
  hspi->begin(HSPI_SCLK, HSPI_MISO, HSPI_MOSI, HSPI_SS); //SCLK, MISO, MOSI, SS
#endif

  //set up slave select pins as outputs as the Arduino API
  //doesn't handle automatically pulling SS low
  pinMode(VSPI_SS, OUTPUT); //VSPI SS
  pinMode(HSPI_SS, OUTPUT); //HSPI SS

}

// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop() {
  //use the SPI buses
  vspiCommand();
  hspiCommand();
  delay(100);
}

void vspiCommand() {
  byte data = 0b01010101; // junk data to illustrate usage

  //use it as you would the regular arduino SPI API
  vspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, LOW); //pull SS slow to prep other end for transfer
  vspi->transfer(data);  
  digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, HIGH); //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
  vspi->endTransaction();
}

void hspiCommand() {
  byte stuff = 0b11001100;
  
  hspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(HSPI_SS, LOW);
  hspi->transfer(stuff);
  digitalWrite(HSPI_SS, HIGH);
  hspi->endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mate I tried the code and it works. I have selected AI Thinker ESP32 that matches my board,and I have selected Flash Mode QIO and also DIO: both working fine. If you may still have the issue I would suggest to select DOUT or DIO.

Basically please check if your board matches the one selected on Tools->Board and check also the selection of 'Flash mode'.

Not all chips support all of these modes. The datasheet is the best source to know what supports what.

```
DIO - SPI host uses the "Dual I/O Fast Read" command (BBh). Two SPI pins are used to write the flash address part of the command, and to read flash data out. Therefore these phases need half the clock cycles compared to standard SPI.
DOUT - SPI host uses the "Dual Output Fast Read" command (3Bh). Two SPI pins are used to read flash data out. Slightly slower than DIO, because the address is written via the single MOSI data pin.
QIO - SPI host uses the "Quad I/O Fast Read" command (EBh). Four SPI pins are used to write the flash address part of the command, and to read flash data out. Therefore these phases need a quarter the clock cycles compared to standard SPI.
QOUT - SPI host uses the "Quad Output Fast Read" command (6Bh). Four SPI pins are used to read the flash data out. Slightly slower than QIO, because the address is written via the single MOSI data pin.
```

ESP-IDF defaults to DIO because some flash chips use a mode bit to enable QIO & QOUT support, and this can vary between manufacturers.

If using DIO/DOUT mode, GPIOs 9 & 10 are available for other uses. However note that if they are wired to the SPI flash chip (as they are in WROOM, for example) then the SPI flash chip may use them for other pin functions. Consult the SPI flash chip data sheet to be sure.

Very interesting discussion on this subject here: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1250

Hope this helps. All the best.